# Running a timer for function which will be called later (python)

Tags: python

```
def child_thread(i):
    global lock

    while True:
        try:
            lock.acquire()
                f1()
                f2()
                f3()
        finally :
            lock.release()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=child_thread, args=(0,))
thread1.start()
```

here i need a timer for f2 function which will be called.were the thread should wait for certain time. I dont want to use sleep.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, you want to delay the call of f2 without using sleep()?

Comment: After calling f2 thread should not call f3 it should wait for sometime

Comment: Why sleep() is not an option then? Looks to be the best choice here to me.

Answer (score 0):

The function will be call after 30.0 seconds

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()
```